# Getting VncRecorder working on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, vnc

I am trying to set Jenkins up to perform continuous testing of some online applications.
I have installed Jenkins on Ubuntu 16.04 and have a slave which is running Windoze 10.
I have installed UltraVnc on the slave and am trying to get VncRecorder to record the test session.
At the moment, my job simply does some random stuff. The console output is as follows:

> Started by user anonymous
>
> Building remotely on Nove1 (UITest) in workspace
>
> C:\Users\Jenkins\workspace\TestTester
>
> [WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
>
> [WS-CLEANUP] Done
>
> Starting xvnc
>
> [TestTester] $ "C:\Program Files\uvnc bvba\UltraVNC\winvnc.exe" -connect host:76 Recording from vnc server: 172.24.27.210:0
>
> Using vnc passwd file: /var/lib/jenkins/secrets/vncpassword
>
> job/TestTester/14/Recording from server: 172.24.27.210:0, to: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TestTester/builds/14/archive/TestTester_14.swf
>
> [TestTester] $ cmd /c call
>
> C:\Users\Jenkins\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson6483326613410629302.bat
>
> C:\Users\Jenkins\workspace\TestTester>echo "Start"  "Start"
>
> C:\Users\Jenkins\workspace\TestTester>exit 0
>
> ERROR: File
>   /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TestTester/builds/14/archive/TestTester_14.swf doesn't exist.
>
> Feature "Record VNC session" failed!
>
> Terminating xvnc.
>
> Finished: FAILURE

I've spent the past 2 days searching on Google and found nothing, so can ay of you good folks help?

Thanks!

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Problem Steps Recorder is a cool Windows tool that can record your actions as a series of images. You can use this tool which is built-into windows :)

```
psr.exe [/start |/stop][/output <fullfilepath>] [/sc (0|1)] [/maxsc <value>]
    [/sketch (0|1)] [/slides (0|1)] [/gui (o|1)]
    [/arcetl (0|1)] [/arcxml (0|1)] [/arcmht (0|1)]
    [/stopevent <eventname>] [/maxlogsize <value>] [/recordpid <pid>]

/start            :Start Recording. (Outputpath flag SHOULD be specified)
/stop            :Stop Recording.
/sc            :Capture screenshots for recorded steps.
/maxsc            :Maximum number of recent screen captures.
/maxlogsize        :Maximum log file size (in MB) before wrapping occurs.
/gui            :Display control GUI.
/arcetl            :Include raw ETW file in archive output.
/arcxml            :Include MHT file in archive output.
/recordpid        :Record all actions associated with given PID.
/sketch            :Sketch UI if no screenshot was saved.
/slides            :Create slide show HTML pages.
/output            :Store output of record session in given path.
/stopevent        :Event to signal after output files are generated.

PSR Usage Examples:

psr.exe
psr.exe /start /output fullfilepath.zip /sc1 /gui 0 /record <PID>
    /stopevent <eventname> /arcetl 1

psr.exe /start /output fullfilepath.xml /gui 0 /recordpid <PID>
    /stopevent <eventname>

psr.exe /start /output fullfilepath.xml /gui 0 /sc 1 /maxsc <number>
    /maxlogsize <value> /stopevent <eventname>

psr.exe /stop

Notes:
1.    Output path should include a directory path (e.g. '.\file.xml').
2.    Output file can either be a ZIP file or XML file
3.    Can't specify /arcxml /arcetl /arcmht /sc etc. if output is not a ZIP file.
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!

Unfortunately, I do actually need a video, however, this may well work as a temporary solution until I can get VNCRecorder working :-)

Comment: Look for command line controllable video recorder over internet or take a open source video recorder and add command line triggers to it

Answer (score 0):

The port number of your VNC server 0 looks suspicious..
What about the firewall settings of your slave - is the vnc port blocked ?
You could verify port of your vncserver with vncviewer 172.24.27.210:.
Regards,
Dimitri (developer of vncrecorder plugin)